# Who are all these Avengers?

Tags: marvel, avengers-vs-x-men

In Avengers Vs X-Men #1 (the new one) we see all these Avengers assembled. But I only recognize maybe a third of these heroes. Who are all these characters?

[image]

Here is a larger version of the image: [Avengers](http://atwitsendcomics.com/test/avengers.png)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From left to right:

- [Spider-Woman](http://marvel.com/universe/Spider-Woman)
- [She-Hulk](http://marvel.com/universe/She-Hulk)
- [Black Panther](http://marvel.com/universe/Black_Panther)
- [Quake](http://marvel.com/universe/Johnson,_Daisy)
- [Storm](http://marvel.com/universe/Storm)
- [Giant-Man](http://marvel.com/universe/Giant-Man)
- [Ms. Marvel](http://marvel.com/universe/Ms._Marvel)
- [Captain Britain](http://marvel.com/universe/Captain_Britain)
- [Mockingbird](http://marvel.com/universe/Mockingbird)
- [The Thing](http://marvel.com/universe/Thing_%28Benjamin_Grimm%29)
- [Hawkeye](http://marvel.com/universe/Hawkeye)
- [Victoria Hand](http://marvel.wikia.com/Victoria_Hand_%28Earth-616%29)
- [Spider Man](http://marvel.com/universe/Spider-Man_%28Peter_Parker%29)
- [War Machine](http://marvel.com/universe/War_Machine)
- [The Vision](http://marvel.com/universe/Vision)
- [Red Hulk](http://marvel.com/universe/Red_Hulk)
- [Squirrel Girl](http://marvel.com/universe/Squirrel_Girl)
- [Thor](http://marvel.com/universe/Thor_%28Thor_Odinson%29)
- [Jessica Jones](http://marvel.com/universe/Jessica_Jones)
- [Luke Cage](http://marvel.com/universe/Cage,_Luke)
- [Dr Strange](http://marvel.com/universe/Dr._Strange)
- [Captain America](http://marvel.com/universe/Winter_Soldier)
- [Wong](http://marvel.com/universe/Wong)
- [Edwin Jarvis](http://marvel.com/universe/Jarvis,_Edwin)
- [Iron Man](http://marvel.com/universe/Iron_Man)
- [Agent 13](http://marvel.com/universe/Carter,_Sharon)
- [Wolverine](http://marvel.com/universe/Wolverine_%28James_Howlett%29)
- [Noh-Varr](http://marvel.com/universe/Marvel_Boy_%28Noh-Varr%29)

Comment: Thanks for the update - I went to edit Wong in and got really surprised when I saw it already in there!

Comment: You did such a great job. Most people just never heard of all of these Avengers and their support staff.

Comment: A *truely* complete answer might link all these characters to their respective marvel wiki pages. That would make it easy to read up on them.

Comment: wow, talk about unreasonable expectations there Jack. @dlanod is expected to create 28 links to save you the google time?

Comment: @JackBNimble You've got enough rep to edit it in. ;)

Comment: @dlanod so now I have to do everything myself...

Comment: I got all but 6 first try. I haven't followed any Marvel comics in...probably 20 years. I have no idea how my brain works.